# Tables inside a form - placing elements vertically instead of horizontally

Tags: html, css

I'm working on an assignment in which the desired output is something along the lines of:

[image: Correct way]

I have been told we are to use a table to do this.

Mine (yet to apply any CSS) looks like:

[image: My way]

My code looks like this:

```
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table border="0">

                    <td>
                        <select name="Continent">
                            <option value="North America">North America</option>
                            <option value="South America">South America</option>
                            <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="Country">
                            <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
                            <option value="Other">Other</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="City">
                            <option value="Ottawa">Ottawa</option>
                            <option value="New York">New York</option>
                            <option value="Sydney">Sydney</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <td>Checkboxes</td>
                </table>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
```

So I guess my question is: How do I get the drop-down lists to stack vertically? I have tried putting them in their own `<tr>` elements, but that does nothing, it just changes the spacing between them slightly.

Do I need to go with the two table approach with two tables within a table?

Is this done in CSS, or do I have to get it somewhat right in html first?

Comment: Did you try <tr><td>...</td></tr>?

Comment: That seems to have done it - I guess that makes sense that I need a <td> in each <tr>

Answer (score 0):

do you mean like this?

```html
<table border="1px solid">
<tr>
<td><select name="Continent">
<option value="North America">North America</option>
<option value="South America">South America</option>
<option value="Asia">Asia</option>
</select></td>
<td rowspan="3">Chexbox</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><select name="Country">
<option value="Canada">Canada</option>
<option value="Other">Other</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><select name="City">
<option value="Ottawa">Ottawa</option>
<option value="New York">New York</option>
<option value="Sydney">Sydney</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
</table>
```